# TypeError- can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes For Finding Time Difference

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to find the time difference between `clock_in` and `clock_out` field. For that i have written logic in `save method` `class Timesheet` in `models.py`. The time differnce between will be stored in `clock_duration`. 
But it gives `TypeError`

Error - while saving data in model

```
TypeError at /timesheet/clock-out/
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Timesheet(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="timesheetuser")
    clock_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    clock_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    clock_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    clock_duration = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.clock_in and self.clock_out:
            self.clock_duration = self.clock_out - self.clock_in
        super(Timesheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "timesheet"
```

Comment: Can you show what value are you saving for your `clock_in` and `clock_out` fields?

Comment: @AmanGarg
When i am printing it is giving these outputs
 `self.clock_out 2019-05-10 16:08:08.923909`
`self.clock_in 2019-05-09 11:12:06.925734+00:00`
I think error is coming because of +00:00 at end of clock_in

Comment: Try using `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`